# How can I use SqlCommand for searching data with multiple input

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sqlcommand

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHBax.png)

I have a datatable as shown in the screenshot, and I want to search a Plant and Panel Tog Number for showing a Group and Coordination.

At first I tried this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [Group],[Coordination] from [Table] where Plant ='" + txt1.Text + "'", con);
```

but how can I do with a multiple inputs?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score -1):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select [Group],[Coordination] from [Table] where Plant LIKE '%" + txt1.Text + "%' OR PanelTogNumber LIKE '%" + txt1.Text + "%'", con);
```

You can try it.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)